# Querying SQL Server for percentages

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-5

I've got three tables: `Customers`, `Origins` and (the mapping table) `CustomerOrigins`. Please note that a customer can originate from more than one `Origin` (for example `Internet`, `Advertisement`, `Newsletter`)

Now I want to show a pie chart of where my customers originate from.

A result should be a `List<string, double>`.

I'm totally lost, even in how to start this whole query... Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a `List<string, double>` because `List<T>` only takes one type parameter. Try this instead:

```
var results =
    (from c in db.Customers
     from o in c.Origins
     group o by o.DisplayName into g
     let total = db.Customers.Count()
     select new
     {
         Origin = g.Key,
         Percent = ((double)g.Count() / (double)total) * 100
     })
    .ToList();
```

This has the possibility of counting a single customer multiple times (once fore each origin), so you won't come up with a list that totals 100%.

If you want a percentage over `CustomerOrigin` records, try this

```
var results =
    (from c in db.Customers
     from o in c.Origins
     group o by o.DisplayName into g
     let total = db.Customers.Sum(x => x.Origins.Count())
     select new
     {
         Origin = g.Key,
         Percent = ((double)g.Count() / (double)total) * 100
     })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, right with the `List<string, double>`. With your query I'm getting the exception: `base {System.SystemException} = {"The key selector type for the call to the 'GroupBy' method is not comparable in the underlying store provider."}`

Comment: `c.Origins` would be a collection (n:m relationship), that's why there's no `OriginName` property there. I tried `group c by c.CustomerOrigins.Select(co => co.Origin) into g` and `group c by c.CustomerOrigins.Select(co => co.Origin).Select(o => o.DisplayName) into g` but to no avail

Comment: @SeToY Okay I think I understand better now -- see my updated answer